# Omission in Comparative clause

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

everyone.

> 1. He dances better than sings.

I have doubts on the omission of a subject after "than". Can I say it as a shortening of:

> 2. He dances better than he sings.

Thanks if you would help.

Comment: (1) is not a valid English sentence.

Comment: The first one seems to be incorrect. Where do you get this sentence from?

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently "ungrammatical" about the sequence [***...can read better than write***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22can+read+better+than+write%22), which has appeared in print several times. But often (as in the cited example) it's likely to be "awkward", so usually this kind of elision (failing to repeat the verb subject) is probably best avoided. For some reason that's not obvious to me, I think the usage is at least more *likely* to sound "natural" in the context of a "helper" verb (such as ***can*** in my Google Books search).